# react-bootstrap grid layout not displaying correctly

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am using typescript, react, and react-bootstrap. I have the following code

```
import React from "react"
import "./homepage/HomePage.css"
import {Col, Container, Row} from "react-bootstrap"



function HomePage() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Administration</h1>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col><p>Hello 1</p></Col>
                    <Col><p>Hello 2</p></Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}
```

and this just shows this
[image]

Comment: make sure you have installed `react-bootstrap`

Comment: Have you imported CSS: [`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export default Homepage;` at the end of your code

And make sure you have imported
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`